# Flutter blue setNotifyValue only showing 21 first characters?

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I try to use the flutter blue library to enable notifications I get not the full string returned.

The code I use:

```
await characteristic.setNotifyValue(true);
characteristic.value.listen((value) {
    print(utf8.decode(value));
});
```

It returns me

```
{"PumpType":"Demopri
```

While I should get

```
{"PumpType":"Demopring","Power":1,"TempWater":28.5,"TempAmbient":22.0,"TempSet":29.0,"ErrorMessages":""}
```

It seems to cut of my message but when I use a serial monitoring application or a native Android application I get the full string, so there is no problem with the peripheral.

The device I ran all my tests on is an Android 10 device and it worked with native Android app.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by changing the MTU size in flutter blue.

```
final mtu = await device.mtu.first;
await device.requestMtu(512);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to request the change of MTU size and then wait for it to be fully negotiated otherwise the stream attached to characteristic didn't trigger for the notify events.

```
await connectedDevice.requestMtu(characteristicMTULength);
int mtu = await device.mtu.first;
while (mtu != characteristicMTULength) {
    print("Waiting for requested MTU");
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    mtu = await device.mtu.first;
}
```